# Info path solution for date calculation

Tags: infopath

I am having two columns

a. Start Date
b. End date

Condition:

While creating a new item it should not allow

- Existing start date, End date. Between dates associated with the
  start and end date.

please let me know a solution for it.

Comment: It's not clear what it's you're trying to say. Can you give further explanation about what you want to do?

Comment: Start Date : 27-09-2017 , 
End Date  :30-09-2017. User cannot able to choose dates between 27-30 as a dates for new item creation.

Comment: What are you using for each date? Textbox or date picker?

Comment: We are using Date Picker control

Answer (score 1):

If you use date picker for all three dates, then my suggestion is following:

Use Validation rule on datePicker3. Condition: if datePicker3 is greater than or equal to startDatePicker and datePicker3 is less or equal to dateEndPicker -> ScreenTip "Date is wrong"

Comment: I am using only 2 date picker control. We are not using 3 date picker controls.
ex: 
Start Date Picker Control : 04-Oct-2017
End Date Picker Control : 08-Oct-2017; 
There is no such 3 date picker control, If one user entered the above values, Next user should not able to choose the date values between 04-Oct and 08-Oct 2017.

Comment: Then the same question - what control are you using for each date? Start date control, End date control and DateInQuestion control?

Comment: We are using only two date pickers controls for choosing the start and end date. 
We need to restrict the users not to choose the dates between the "existing start" and "existing end dates" when they created a new item.
We are not using one more date picker to achieve this. Please let me know the possible ways.

Comment: So you have "existing start" and "existing end dates"? And two date pickers which values must not be between "existing start" and "existing end dates"? Then where are you getting "existing start" and "existing end dates" from? Textboxes?

Comment: No we have to query it from SharePoint existing List items.